# JMeter JSR 223 language js Vs javascript

Tags: javascript, jmeter, jsr223

About JSR 223 Sampler languages,

I can choose between

> javascript (ECMAScript ECMA 262 Edition 51 / Oracle Nashorn
>   1.8.0_144)

and

> js (ECMAScript ECMA 262 Edition 51 / Oracle Nashorn 1.8.0_144)

and

> nashorn (ECMAScript ECMA 262 Edition 51 / Oracle Nashorn 1.8.0_144)

What's the difference? it seems that they are the same as JavaScript.

Can I edit the list somehow? remove unused script languages?

(There's also ecmascript language with same properties)

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think you will be able to remove entries from there as the drop down is being populated on-the-fly using [ScriptEngineManager.getEngineFactories()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/script/ScriptEngineManager.html#getEngineFactories--) method which performs discovery of available scripting engines in [JMeter Classpath](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#classpath).

With regards which language to use `js` or `javascript` the answer is **none**. It is recommended to use [Groovy language](http://www.groovy-lang.org/) for any form of scripting in JMeter tests as well-behaved Groovy scripts can be compiled and cached therefore their performance will be pretty like to "normal" Java code while other scripting languages are being interpreted each time they are being called so when it comes to high loads your JSR223 test element using JavaScript might become a performance bottleneck and ruin your test.

References:

- [JMeter Best Practices: JSR223 Elements](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#jsr223)
- [Apache Groovy - Why and How You Should Use It](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black)