# JMeter add velocity language to JSR 223 Sampler

Tags: jmeter, velocity, scripting-language, jsr223, apache-velocity

I want to use velocity language as Scripting language in JMeter's `JSR 223 Sampler`.

According to the [list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11838369/where-can-i-find-a-list-of-available-jsr-223-scripting-languages) velocity can be used in JSR223,

According to the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45668451/jmeter-jsr-223-language-js-vs-javascript) velocity should be added to JMeter classpath for discovery of available scripting engines.

How can I add velocity as a Scripting engine in JMeter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Download new [velocity engine scripting version 2.0](http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/velocity/velocity-engine-scripting/2.0/) in order to support scripting engine.

Put velocity-engine-scripting-2.0.jar in JMeter's lib folder.

When JMeter loaded it can find velocity as scripting engine and use it.

**EDIT**

Also add relevant velocity jar(s) as velocity-engine-core-2.0.jar
[image]