# Previewing Velocity Template

Tags: velocity

I'm editing velocity templates. these are used to generate PDFs. The problem is that I can't preview them. I can't see how the template will look when rendered. Are there any tools that can be used for that? I've tried googling and I can't find anything.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this addresses what you need, but I created a [velocity-template-tester](https://github.com/devatherock/velocity-template-tester) a few years ago when I worked with Velocity templates. It has a UI where you can specify a template like `<html>Hello ${user}</html>` and parameters like `{"user":"test"}` or `user=test` and it'll show you the expanded template as `<html>Hello test</html>`. But it doesn't render the output as such.

If your output will be internally HTML and you want it rendered, you could use a REST API that is also part of the tester in [Postman](https://www.postman.com/). Postman has a `Preview` button in the `Body` tab of the response which can be used to render HTML. The API accepts both JSON and YAML input. YAML input makes it easier to manually test multi-line templates. A sample API call with YAML input looks something like below:

```
curl --location --request POST 'http://localhost:8080/api/expandTemplate' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/x-yaml' \
--header 'Accept: text/html' \
--data-raw 'template: |
  <html>
    <body>
      Hello ${user}
    </body>
  </html>
parameters:
  user: test'
```