# JMeter's JSR 233 - Edit option in language is irrelevant

Tags: scripting, jmeter, jsr223

In JMeter JSR 233 element There's an Edit option in language Combo box,

If you leave empty it chooses by default groovy, but if you write engine name it's error prone and irrelevant because according to [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45668451/jmeter-jsr-223-language-js-vs-javascript)

> drop down is being populated on-the-fly using
>   `ScriptEngineManager.getEngineFactories()` method which performs
>   discovery of available scripting engines in JMeter Classpath.

So if you can choose in drop down **only relevant** engines why you need to input manually different (not working) engines?

Is it a bug of JMeter? or is there a special reason/usage?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The edit option comes from the fact that a generic combo box component is used for the GUI of this element.

One possible case I see is user having some engine in JMeter install A.
He saves his script.
He opens it with JMeter install B where this engine is not installed, if this option didn't exist, he would lose this setting.

Comment: But then install B will still failed, tested with velocity install A only: `Response message: javax.script.ScriptException: Cannot find engine named: 'velocity', ensure you set language field in JSR223 Test Element: JSR223 Sampler`

Comment: Yes but the engine used is not lost. User adds it and restarts